# Flatten json to get multiple columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample dataframe as

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2], 'fruits' :[
    [{'name': u'mango', 'cost': 100, 'color': u'yellow', 'size': 12}],
    [{'name': u'mango', 'cost': 150, 'color': u'yellow', 'size': 21},
     {'name': u'banana', 'cost': 200, 'color': u'green', 'size': 10} ]
]})
```

I would like to flatten the `fruits` column to get new columns like `name, cost, color` and `size`. One `id` can have more than 1 fruit entry. For example `id 2` has information for 2 fruits `mango` and `banana`

```
print(sample_df)

                                              fruits  id
0  [{'name': 'mango', 'cost': 100, 'color': 'yell...   1
1  [{'name': 'mango', 'cost': 150, 'color': 'yell...   2
```

In the output I would like to have 3 records, 1 record with fruit information for `id 1` and 2 records for fruit information for `id 2`

Is there a way to parse this structure using pandas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First [`unnesting`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939) your columns , then `concat` the values after called `DataFrame`

```
s=unnesting(sample_df,['fruits']).reset_index(drop=True)

df=pd.concat([s.drop('fruits',1),pd.DataFrame(s.fruits.tolist())],axis=1)
df
Out[149]: 
   id   color  cost    name  size
0   1  yellow   100   mango    12
1   2  yellow   150   mango    21
2   2   green   200  banana    10
```

---

```
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx = df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1 = pd.concat([
        pd.DataFrame({x: np.concatenate(df[x].values)}) for x in explode], axis=1)
    df1.index = idx

    return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1), how='left')
```

---

Method 2

```
sample_df.set_index('id').fruits.apply(pd.Series).stack().apply(pd.Series).reset_index(level=0)
Out[159]: 
   id   color  cost    name  size
0   1  yellow   100   mango    12
0   2  yellow   150   mango    21
1   2   green   200  banana    10
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. When i apply this to real data, which is messy, it returns me an error - `ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated` . I dont know how to best resolve this.

Comment: @Regressor filter before running`unnesting` `sample_df =sample_df [sample_df.fruits.astype(bool)].copy()`

Comment: @Regressor ok , let us try the another way , I will update

Comment: okay let me try running that new method on the actual dataset.

Comment: when i try the other method on actual dataset, it returns me the `id` and the json as is.

Comment: @Regressor try both my method with the sample dataframe you provided to us , if that work , pleaqse find the difference between this and your real data (**Your question can not reproduced your problem**)

Comment: in Method 2, does `set_index()` require an `int` datatype?

Comment: @Regressor nope